# combine data from two tables to form needed result set

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table for students that stores all of their quiz info like the question and the answer selected.

I have another table that stores all the quiz data for a quiz.

they look like this:

> table quiz_session_info

```
quiz_id
quiz_question_id
quiz_answer_id
quiz_question_text
quiz_answer_text
quiz_session_datetime
student_name
```

> table quiz_data

```
quiz_id
quiz_question_id
quiz_answer_id
quiz_question_text
quiz_answer_text
```

The 2 fields that both tables have in common are a quiz_question_id and a quiz_answer_id.

I have a query that shows all the quiz questions and answers the student selected like this:

```
SELECT quiz_question_id, quiz_answer_id, quiz_question_text,
quiz_answer_text AS "Selected Answer", quiz_session_datetime, student_name
FROM quiz_session_info
```

I was wondering if there's a way to include in my query, all the questions, and question answers that the user did NOT select.

For example, if there's a question that asks:

> What part(s) are parts commonly found in a car?

```
 a) brakes
 b) engine
 c) headlights
 d) handle-bars
 e) turn signals
```

And the student only selected item **"a"** and item **"b"**.

Well, **"a"** and **"b"** would be in my quiz_session_info table, but I also want to show items they did not select (**c,d,e**).

Is there a way to get this info from my quiz_data table and show that data in my query results and label them as unselected answers?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's quite feasible. Is that your only question?

Comment: @HABO No, I was hoping for an example of how to change my current query to include the needed data.  Thanks!

Comment: Try using `quiz_session_info as si inner join quiz_data as qd on qd.quiz_id = si.quiz_id and qd.quiz_question_id = si.quiz_question_id`  to get all of the answers for each question. If the `quiz_answer_id` values match then you have the selected answer for a given question. Aside: You may also want to normalize your schema.